Getting Redirect URI Mismatch error in Azure AD b2C
New in Azure AD B2C, and need your help.
I am getting a redirect URI mismatch error while trying to use the Run User Flow option in Azure Portal. I have verified the redirect URL configured in the app. Please refer to the screenshots below.



This is the error I am getting
http://localhost:8080/redirect#error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=AADB2C90006%3a+The+redirect+URI+%27https%3a%2f%2fjwt.ms%27+provided+in+the+request+is+not+registered+for+the+client+id+%27edd89caf-3664-4d6c-81ae-75aac966dbe6%27.%0d%0aCorrelation+ID%3a+c33cf41f-b2a7-4de5-ae92-2e44ba878ec9%0d%0aTimestamp%3a+2024-10-08+12%3a02%3a07Z%0d%0a

Please let me know what am I doing wrong here

That looks correct; I've sometimes had it take a while to update and it worked a few minutes later. Can you try again?

Yes, I agree with @juunas. Initially, I too faced same error due to delay in redirect URI update. After some time, when I tried again, I got token successfully after running user flow like this https://i.imgur.com/z3KCnB4.png

yes. it started working some time. Thank you guys.


Yes, I agree with @juunas. The redirect URI changes might take a few
minutes to propagate across Azure AD B2C.

I have one app registration with redirect URI configured as https://jwt.ms in Web platform as below:

I created one user flow named B2C_1_signupsignin and selected above app registration before running it:

Initially, I too faced similar error due to delay in redirect URI not updating instantly after configuration.

When I tried again after some time, user flow ran successfully and gave token like this:

If you've just made the updates, give it a bit of time (typically a few minutes) and try again as there will be delay to reflect.
